# To find out Armstrong number in between numbers

Tags: java, numbers

Below is my code.

```
package com.ofss.java.examples;

import java.util.Scanner;

class ArmstrongNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 0, a;
        int n1, n2;//Range in which armstrong number need to find

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        n1 = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number");
        n2 = s.nextInt();

        for (int i = n1; i <= n2; ++i) {
            while (i > 0) {
                a = i % 10;
                System.out.println(a);
                i = i / 10;
                System.out.println(i);
                c = c + (a * a * a);
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            if (i == c)
                System.out.println(c + "armstrong number");
            else
                System.out.println(c + "Not armstrong number");

        }
    }
}
```

1. I am getting incorrect results after executing. Code runs for infinite number till you stops it. It must print number between 151-154 (153 as armstrong).
2. Also, it is incorrectly printing 153 as not Armstrong number.

[Armstrong Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number)

> ...is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and give us the definition for the Armstrong number, assuming not everyone reading would know this.

Comment: Do not Change the Loop variable inside the Loop. I think because of `i=i/10;` i will never be greater than n2

Answer (score 1):

You should not change `i` since this is also used in

```
for (int i = n1; i <= n2; ++i)
```

Or you will probably never exit that loop eiter since you expect `i` to be negative at the end of the first iteration. Hard to increment until it reach `n2`.

Use a different variable to keep track of `i` safely.

```
    int j = i;
    while(j > 0) ...
```

---

About [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number):

> *Armstrong number is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits*

You need to put each digit to the power of the length of the number (the number of digit).

```
153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3
1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4
```

Here is the method for it :

```
public static boolean isArmstrongNumber(int number){
    int power = Integer.toString(number).length(); //just to get the number of digit...

    int tmp = number;
    int digit , sum = 0;

    while(tmp > 0){
        digit = tmp % 10;
        sum += Math.round(Math.pow(digit , power));
        tmp /= 10;
    }

    return sum == number;
}
```

Using this check from 0 to 10.000 gives :

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   153
>   370
>   371
>   407
>   1634
>   8208
>   9474

Same as *Wikipedia* :

> The sequence of base 10 narcissistic numbers starts: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208, 9474, ...

Note that using a method remove the risk of forgetting to reset your variable like `c` in your case. Correcting this would give you a few more "correct" results (well the one with 3 digits)

You can also use less mathematics to read the number and use `char[]`, remember that you need to substract `'0'` value to get the numeric value for a character :

```
public static boolean isArmstrongNumber(int number){
    char[] digits = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();

    int power = digits.length;
    int sum = 0;

    for(char c : digits){
        int digit = c - '0';
        sum += Math.round(Math.pow(digit, power));
    }

    return sum == number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things.

1. you are updating i everytime as you have used it in while, so use different variable than i for this calculation.

   int num = i;
2. c is used to compare sum of cube is same as number but you are not resetting it once the one iteration is over.  so make c=0 inside for loop.

   c = 0;

Also while printing you are using c, there should be i which is correct and real number.

Below is the working code you may try.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int c = 0, a;
    int n1, n2;//Range in which armstrong number need to find

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number");
    n1 = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number");
    n2 = s.nextInt();
    for (int i = n1; i <= n2; ++i)
    {

        int num = i;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            a = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            c = c + (a * a * a);

        }
        if (i == c)
            System.out.println(i + "armstrong number");
        else
            System.out.println(i + "Not armstrong number");
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, if it worked you should mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

public class ArmstrongNumber {

```
private final int n1, n2;

public ArmstrongNumber(int n1, int n2) {
    this.n1 = n1;
    this.n2 = n2;
}

protected static boolean isArmstrong(int n) {
    if(n < 0)
        return false;

    int remaining=n;
    int sumCube=0;

    while (remaining>0) {

        int d = remaining % 10;
        sumCube += cube(d);
        remaining /= 10;
    }

    return n == sumCube;
}

private static int cube(int d) {
    return d*d*d;
}

public Integer[] find() {

    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = n1; i <= n2; ++i)
    {

        if (isArmstrong(i))
            results.add(i);
    }

    return results.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

}

Comment: Good start, a lot of "non-necessary" code here though. Not sure a class is needed here. And by the way, this will only give 4 correct value.

Answer (score -2):

There are lot of things to improve in your code. One of the working logics as below:

```
for (int i = n1; i <= n2; ++i) {
    int sum = 0, remainder = 0, digits = 0, temp = 0;

    temp = i;
    while (temp != 0) {
        digits++;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }

    temp = i;
    while (temp != 0) {
        remainder = temp % 10;
        sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(remainder, digits);
        temp = temp / 10;
    }

    if (i == sum)
        System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number.");
    else
        System.out.println(i + " isn't an Armstrong number.");
}
```

Comment: I request developers who had downvoted to submit comment as well so that i could improve my answer. I thought, my suggested logic
1. will work for any number of digits number. 
2. make sense to use local variable inside the for loop than outside. 
3. logic is clear and concise